# Настройка .htaccess для OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

Необходимо доработать стандартный файл .htaccess для OpenCart
Пытаюсь настроить редиректы,

- с index.php на без index.php
- Без слеша в конце на со слешом
- А так же все дело перевести на https

Все это нужно сделать 1 редиректом, сейчас index.php работает, но с 2 редиректами, сразу на https потом убирает index.php. Редиректы со слешами вообще не работают

```
#Убираем index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^https://site.com$ https://site.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

# Убираем index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\z
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/? [R=301,L]

# Добавляем слеш
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Редирект на https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Ставить всё после `RewriteBase /`